# Error: spawn ENOENT at errnoException (child_process.j2:980:11) when using Node.js child_process using non-root user

Tags: node.js, spawn, child-process

I ran into this error using node.js v0.10.12 in MacOS and linux, this piece of code
work fine in windows 7.
The only differences is on windows 7 I have admin id, on MacOSX and linux , I am not root and just plan user.

Do we need to be root to work with child_process?
Any clue about why it fails on some OS and not all?
Thanks so much,

This is the code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
 try {
var child = spawn('node', ['plusone.js']);
//call every minute
setInterval(function() {
//
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
child.stdin.write(number +'\n');
child.stdout.once('data', function(data) {
console.log('child replied to '+ number +' with ' +data);
 });     
},1500); 


             child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
             process.stdout.write(data);

             });


          } catch (e)
         {
           console.log("entering catch block");
          console.log(e);
         }
```

Comment: ENOENT means it cannot find the command/file you are trying to execute. Is `node` found in the PATH for that user.

Answer (score 2):

Hi All: I think I got my  answer.
The reason why it did not work on the other OS is my configuration.

If did not configure the node on the system path so that it can be accessible everywhere unless the path is specified.

Comment: I tried to search online for exactly the same problem but only to get a lot of answers about ImageMagick, while I already had it installed years ago. Finally made it work according to this one. The reason turns out to be Debian's nodejs's executable is named `nodejs` instead of `node`. A simple `ln` would solve the problem. Thank you!